# Unknown Typescript construct

Tags: typescript

In another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355451/how-do-i-add-a-static-method-to-my-typescript-class) I saw this Typescript statement which I not fully understand:

```
export var SuperUser = (id:Number):ISuperUser => {
        return new SuperUserImpl(id);       
}
```

I understand that `SuperUser` is a function which expects one `id:Number` parameter which executes the body between the brackets `{...}`.

But I don't know what the `:ISuperUser` part means.

What does it mean? How to read this line properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, it means the function *returns* a type compatible with `ISuperUser`.

```
export var SuperUser = (id: /* parameter type */ Number): /* return type */ ISuperUser => {
    return new SuperUserImpl(id);       
}
```

If you attempted to `return 5` in the function body, you should see a compilation warning because a `Number` is compatible with `ISuperUser`.

## Additional Notes

Sometimes, `=>` is used to declare the return type. This is only used when a `:` would cause confusion. For example, in the interface below.

Code:

```
var example1 = function (param: string): number {
    return 1;
}

interface Example2 {
    method: (param: string) => number;
}
```

This is a contrived example, because you could describe it more cleanly using `method2(param: string): number;` within an interface - but you will find other similar examples when using inline type definitions. The compiler will normally give you a warning `=> expected` if you get mixed up.

Comment: Ah, I thought the return type has to be stated after the `=>`.

Comment: In this case, the `=>` is a lambda for creating the function. You will occasionally see it being used for type information where a `:` would be confusing.

Comment: Oh so `=>` can have two meanings? Either lambda or type information? That would clarify a lot of confusion :)